# Override jQuery on click handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie when it comes to jQuery and I'm hoping if there's a way to override an existing on click function.

The code is as follows:

```
$('.woo-star-rating').on('click', function() {
    $('.woo-star-rating-filled').width( $(this).attr('data-rating') * 25 )
});
```

and I'd like to change the number *25* to *21* inside my own .js file.

```
$('.woo-star-rating').on('click', function() {
    $('.woo-star-rating-filled').width( $(this).attr('data-rating') * 21 )
});
```

Comment: What are you asking? Simply change 25 to 21 and save the js file

Comment: Seems like I didn't explain it properly. The first code is part of a plugin and therefore I can't modify the original code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the existing `click` event handler using the [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method add your new click event.

```
var $rating = $('.woo-star-rating');

$rating.off('click');
$rating.on('click', function() {
    $('.woo-star-rating-filled').width( $(this).attr('data-rating') * 21 )
});
```

This can be chained into:

```
$('.woo-star-rating').off('click').on('click', function() {
    $('.woo-star-rating-filled').width( $(this).attr('data-rating') * 21 )
});
```

Here's a working example:

```js
// add junk event
$('#test-button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('first button click');
});

// remove first event
$('#test-button').off('click');

// add new event, only this will fire on click
$('#test-button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('second button click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test-button">Test Button</button>
```